# Do each parent directories need to have their own node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on an app powered by node which has a few (three) different folders. It looks like this:

```
Client- 
Server-
      -node_modules
         -mongoose
Database-
     -index.js
Config-
    -credentials.js
```

I have made an `exports` object with all of my passwords and put it in the database folder (this way I can easily ignore it from being checked in to any version control).

I am wondering if there is a way to have *ALL* of the `node_modules` used by my `server` and `database` directories in the server directory so that the `package.json` file in my `server` directory would contain all of the needed packages for the "backend" of my project.

However, when I do this, and try to `require(mongoose)` from the `Database/index.js` file, I get `"cannot find module"` errors. I tried the following combinations and still get the error in every case:
`require(mongoose)` `require(../server/mongoose)` `require(../server/node_modules/mongoose)`

Installing the `mongoose` module directly in the `Database` directory fixes this problem but this means that I have to have a `node_modules` (and thus `package.json`) file in  each directory.  Is that the right way to fix this issue or is there a more simple solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you find interesting having a look at the following article: **["Where does Node.js and require() look for modules?"](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)**, in order to understand why the different ways you are trying to "require" `mongoose` are not actually working - and that is because the way you are organizing your code (your `node_modules` directory is inside your `Server` and your `Database` directory is under the `/` - root directory).

So, in your case, you will have to specify your `/Database/index.js` the relative file path to `mongoose` in order to find your module:

```
require('../server/node_modules/mongoose');
```

Another solution (I personally organize my code like this) would be moving your database code within the server code; after all, it's all backend code.

Answer (score 0):

I aware this not elegant way but i have an advice for your case.

You can try like below;.

```
var mongoose = require('../server/node_modules/mongoose/index');
```

I was simulated your case in my local and this worked.